# How resilient is Ubuntu to repeated "power-off" shutdowns?

Tags: hardware, shutdown, restart

My company is considering the use of Ubuntu as an OS for use on a hardware device.

It would be installed on compact flash drive - apparently this is not standard flash drive but a specific type of memory that is supposed to "cope" with immediate power shutdown (I am not sure how this is achieved but they are supposedly a "high end" card).

The units that would be run using Ubuntu are the type of units that will not be gracefully shutdown - the power cable would be removed and that is that.

Can anybody give me some advice on the potential problems that can occur? Is Ubuntu a good system that can deal with this kind of power outage and reboot successfully on next startup?

I realise that nothing is unbreakable, but is it a commonly used OS for an embedded setup? Is it asking for trouble to use Ubuntu in this kind of environment?

Comment: Is there any way you could incorporate a UPS or battery backup into your devices?  Even a relatively small one would give Linux enough time to shut things down gracefully.  Ideally, you'd want to tell your applications first (as soon as the UPS kicks in) so they could shut down before Linux forces them to do so in very little time.

Comment: I wonder, would it be possible to use a file system that has a copy-on-write feature, such as ZFS? Then theoretically it would be impossible to get corruption since on next boot the restoration would happen until the last known-good state of the FS, avoiding any possible partially written data afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Note: this answer is from the perspective of a production environment where data loss or downtime can lead to loss of money, customers, industrial equipment malfunctioning, etc. If you are just tinkering with a Raspberry Pi at home, I'd say there's no problem... :)

I would *not* recommend Ubuntu in its default configuration, and the (default) ext4 filesystem by design, for an embedded environment where there would be repetitive "ungraceful" shutdowns like you suggest.

If I'm correct, you're using Ubuntu 8.04, which supports ext3 at best. While both ext3/ext4 use [*journaling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) as a way to maintain file (write) integrity and to aid in recovery, these should not be relied on when "pull the power cable" is the rule rather than the exception.

- The ideal option, assuming that your system will not need dynamic reconfiguration once set up, is to mount its root filesystem read-only and to entirely use a temporary in-memory partition when operational (like the LiveCD does). In this case, the system would return to its "initial" configuration whenever booted up.
- To store (a limited amount of) user data in a non-volatile way, you could create a secondary partition, perhaps using a filesystem optimized for flash media such as JFFS2 depending on the internal structure of the CF card.  To reduce the chances of data corruption by pulling the plug, you could disable hardware write caching for the device, and mount it in synchronous (sync) mode, disabling write caching by the kernel. These options may severely affect throughput and performance, even on a "high-end" CF card, so you would have to take the intended use into consideration too.

Comment: I read on a blog that the default Linux file system (ext) is not good at handling random shut down.

I had a system which used to overheat and turn off automatically. Finally, I had to get my hard disk replaced because it failed.

Comment: I have to call FUD.  The ext3/4 journal most certainly can be relied on to keep the filesystem in working order when pulling the plug.  It does nothing however, for user data, so applications writing files at the time of the crash may corrupt their data unless they are careful.  Also enabling sync on flash media will not just slow things down drastically, but will lead to the flash wearing out sooner.  Also JFFS and YAFFS are for use on direct NOR flash built into embedded systems; ext4 works better on consumer type devices that do internal wear leveling.

Comment: @psusi: I did not say that *filesystem* integrity would be compromised. And I already noted the effect of sync. Rec changed to JFFS2 which does support NAND. Note that wear-leveling is flush-agnostic so FUDback A wearing out sooner claim.

Comment: As far as I am aware these cards are really good - but currently DOS is used. The devices need to record instrumentation data at regular intervals. As this data is business critical it sounds like I better avoid using ubuntu. I just cant believe that DOS seems the more reliable approach. Anyway thanks very much for this excellent thourough answer!! The cards we use have internal wear leveling as far as I know.

Comment: @isx So in summary, it would be fine in terms of no file corruption so that it can reboot, but any (busines critical) log files that my software will write may end up trashed?

Comment: @mathematician1975: thanks, *how* you will use it puts a whole different spin on it. Put it this way: if a log file is being written to at the moment the plug is pulled, that file may be in jeopardy. Additionally, Ubuntu will want to do an fsck on the filesystem when booted up again. While the FAT filesystem DOS uses is notoriously flaky, overall DOS is in a way more reliable for your purposes because it is a *ridiculously simple* OS compared to current Ubuntu/Linux -- no caching, no system logs being written to, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were getting at viz. wear-leveling and flush.  My point was that sync leads to more writes, which will wear out flash sooner.  Also when using the ext3/4 journal, a `fsck` is NOT performed after power fail; the kernel uses the journal to make fast repairs when the fs is mounted.  Avoiding a long `fsck` after a crash is the whole reason journaling was added.

Comment: @psusi: flash durability is in write cycles *per cell*, not *per device* -- small repeated writes via sync of total size N, vs. one buffered write of total size N should have the same effect on flash life.

Comment: @izx Well I have to agree with the overall answer. We ran 24 hour test restarting ubuntu on the embedded device every 2 minutes. Came in this morning and it is now unable to boot (GRUB error) so that pretty much discounts it for our purposes. DOS it is then.

Comment: @mathematician1975: if you want to use Linux for these purposes, you need a real-time/embedded distro, maybe something like [ucLinux](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uclinux.org%2F&ei=DMMHUPCTIOKe2AXx6eS8BA&usg=AFQjCNGy6oKcCID682fLKahUxyb1Z26MTg&sig2=LViA9ZZ8o1SIZyoCRV_cJQ), not a full-blown desktop/server distro like Ubuntu... :)

Comment: YEah I have come to the same conclusion. It was all a learning experience though. At least I know what not to do now.

Comment: @mathematician1975 - if this is "business critical data", then surely you want to put in a UPS? No operating system on Earth can guarantee corruption-free data when you pull the plug at any time. As already mentioned, making everything read-only apart from the data would help, and a light Linux distro can shut down safely and rapidly on a signal from a UPS.

Answer (score 5):

The Operating System will be fine as long as it is setup for read-only use. LiveCD's have a setup like that, so that you can power them off at anytime, and the OS will not suffer harm.

On a read-write drive, ext4 filesystems are very resilient. But no matter the filesystem, any drive that is writable will be subject to corrupt files.

Answer (score 1):

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type

```
journalctl -xb
```

to view the system logs, `systemctl reboot` to reboot and `systemctl default` or `exit` to boot into default mode.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for maintenance  (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to continue):

I've seen that message everytime after power failure,  any Windows OS is far more resilient to power failure, than Linux as default configuration.

I'n my city the power grid shutdown twice a month in summer.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using Ubuntu for about 18 months, and I've experimented with all sorts of programs and downloads. My opinion on Ubuntu is that it is far and away the the most stable operateing system available.

Programs and downloads that would have demolished windows OS's are just brushed aside by Ubuntu and Kubuntu, Ubuntu is really easy to use, has everything you could ever need, office and work applications are excellent, and it never gets a virus or trojens like Windows.

Kubuntu seems to have a few more toys, it's a bit harder to get to grips with but just as robust as ubuntu. The only downside with either is that you can't play 3d games or watch skygo like you can with Windows, but apart from that can't see any reason to use anything else.

Comment: This doesn't really address this question, though, which is asking specifically about how well an Ubuntu system hold up across multiple sudden power loss events.