# Question regarding power outages affect on ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, shutdown, performance, reboot, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How resilient is Ubuntu to repeated “power-off” shutdowns?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164726/how-resilient-is-ubuntu-to-repeated-power-off-shutdowns)

Due to some reasons, sudden power outages are common at my place so my current operating system "Windows" shut down improperly most of the time but this had no bad affects till now. So i would like to know if i use Ubuntu, will abnormal shut down's affect it's system files or any other performance issue? If so then please explain :)

Your help will be very much appreciated.